# Inconsistent performance of IndexedDB initialization

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, indexeddb, dexie

I'm playing with IndexedDB. My application has 5 DBs:

[image]

Each DB contains from 1000 to 1000000 items in it.
When the application starts I measure how long it takes to initialize the first DB.
The result is inconsistent, it varies from 50ms to 3500ms:

- refresh the tab: 70, 2000, 300;
- re-open the tab: 2000;
- re-open the browser: 3500;
- close the tab and open in 10 mins: 2100;

Do you know what causes the inconsistency? How can I make it consistent?

Comment: How certain are you that the browser initializes the DBs in the same order on each page load?

Comment: Tom, I don’t initialise the other DBs, only the first one. By initialising I mean opening connections to the DB.

Comment: When I have only one DB I can see the inconsistency as well, it varies from 30ms to 1000ms. Having many DBs just makes it worse.

Comment: Seems weird that you have several databases. You should only need one, tbh, and separate each entry by key. I'm assuming you're reading all the data at once, and not one key at a time or something similar. This article explains some part of why Indexeddb can be slow: https://rxdb.info/slow-indexeddb.html